# gradle publish does not pick up artifacts: "Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions."

Tags: gradle, artifactory, publish, tar

I'm migrating a java project from gradle 2.x to 5.3.1.

The last problem is that no artefacts (a tar in our case) are published to artifactory.

The config in main `build.gradle` is

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
    project.ext {
        artifactoryConfig = new File(project.gradle.gradleUserHomeDir, "artifactory.gradle")
    }
    if (artifactoryConfig.exists()) {
        apply plugin: 'maven'
        apply from: artifactoryConfig
    }
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url $OUR_ARTIFACTORY }
    }
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }
}
artifactory {
    publish {
        contextUrl = "${artifactoryBaseUrl}"
        repository {
            repoKey = "libs-release-local"
            username = "${artifactoryUsername}"
            password = "${artifactoryPassword}"
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repoKey = 'repos'
    }
}
```

And in the module

```
task('dist', type: Tar) {
    dependsOn('jar')
    archiveName "$MODULE-${version}.${extension}"
...
}
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication)
                {
                    artifact dist {
                    }
                }
    }
}
configurations.archives.artifacts.clear()
artifacts {
    archives dist
}
```

Now when I do `./gradlew --info :$MODULE:artifactoryPublish` it complains about missing outputs and does not publish the tar to artifactory.

How to fix this?

```
> Task :$MODULE:artifactoryPublish
Task ':$MODULE:artifactoryPublish' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
:$MODULE:artifactoryPublish (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:artifactoryDeploy (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :artifactoryDeploy
Task ':artifactoryDeploy' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Deploying build descriptor to: $OUR_ARTIFACTORY/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under $OUR_ARTIFACTORY/artifactory/webapp/builds/$MODULE/1554465369336
:artifactoryDeploy (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.155 secs.
```

Comment: Regarding “it complains about missing outputs”: that doesn’t look suspicious to me per se as the tasks in question don’t have any file-based outputs. What _is_ actually deployed on Artifactory? I’m asking because it says: “Build successfully deployed.”

Comment: @Chriki Nothing is deployed to artifactory (the build is empty). That is the problem.

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: @Abhimaan Yes; see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was to add

```
artifactoryPublish {
    publications('mavenJava')
}
```

Comment: yes, this worked for me, I was using the artifactory plugin with a defaults block that wasn't being picked up?

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = "${artifactory_publish_repo}"
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        defaults {
            publications "pluginPublication", "pluginMarkerMaven"
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that the url and credentials were null. It resulted in the same error message(Task has not declared any outputs).

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = artifactoryUrl

    publish {
        repository {
            username = artifactoryPublishUser
            password = artifactoryPublishPassword
```

Answer (score 1):

The most valuable hint is a running example

https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/gradle-android-example